# Angular firebase auth - how to retrieve information from database(files url)?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I've made upload service which lets users upload an avatar photo, which is only seen by themselves, I am using auth uid to define upload path in both storage and database. There are no problems with upload, **I am only having problems with retrieving that information from the database. Take a look at my code with more explanations below:**

upload.service.ts (***where I define upload and get***)  :

As I said there is no problem with uploads, there is ***only one problem right now with getLitsupload()***. I can't get file data and can't show it on the page. I get the error in that function :

> Cannot read property 'snapshotChanges' of undefined
>       at UploadService.get [as getListUploads]

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireAction, DatabaseSnapshot, AngularFireObject,
} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Upload } from './upload';
import {AngularFireAuth} from "angularfire2/auth";
import {AuthService} from "../../../core/auth.service";
import {Profile} from "../../../core/profile";

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {
  uploadRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  profile = {} as Profile;
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,
              public firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              public auth: AuthService,) {

    //path of uplaoded file data
    this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
      this.uploadRef = this.db.list<any>(`profile/${auth && auth.email && auth.uid}/uploads`);
   console.log("Photo uplaod to authuid/profile/uploads")
    })

  }
//getting uploaded files/file (main problem here --> cannot read snapshotChanges() of undefined 
  get getListUploads(): Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot>[]> {
    return this.uploadRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
  }

  //upload to storage
  set pushUpload(upload: Upload) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`uploads/${auth && auth.email && auth.uid}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);
      uploadTask.on('state_changed',
        (snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) => {
          upload.progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }, () => {
          upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
          upload.name = upload.file.name
          this.saveFileData(upload);
        }
      );
    })

  }


  // Save file data (url,name,size etc.) to profile/authuid/uploads

  private saveFileData(upload : Upload): void {
    this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe(auth => {
    this.db.object(`profile/${auth && auth.email && auth.uid}/uploads`).set(upload);
    })
  }

}
```

**Upload works fine in both storage and database:**

[image: Database works fine]

What I am doing wrong and why I can't retrieve files data?

Bonus: If there are other ways of doing same, please write some examples.

Edit :

all works fine if I write all functions without **auth**.

This works :

```
  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,
              public firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth,
              public auth: AuthService,) {

    //path of uplaoded file data
      this.uploadRef = this.db.list<any>(`profile`);
   console.log("Photo uplaod to authuid/profile/uploads")

  }
```

But then I am getting all the photos not only one (users avatar) :

```
  get getListUploads(): Observable<AngularFireAction<DatabaseSnapshot>[]> {
    return this.uploadRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
  }
```

Comment: `this.firebaseAuth.authState.subscribe` is an `async` function and most likely you call `this.uploadRef.snapshotChanges()` before its callback is called. If I were you I would better call methods on services when needed. So you wouldnt need to call `authState.subscribe` on constructor. Keep logged/loggedout state/object in BehaviorSubject with an id/$key and subscribe to it if need to upload etc